# Correct way to write words with - in formula

Tags: math-mode, spacing, letterspacing

I am wondering if there is a generally preferred way to write words with `-` in formula.

For example:

`$k-distance$`

or

`$k \textit{-} distance$`

of maybe something better?

Comment: `$k$-distance`.  Only the `k` should be in math mode.

Comment: even inside equations? Suppose `$k-distance(p)$` How should I write it?

Comment: never use math italic for words, the font is designed to make adjacent letters _not_ look like a word, also `-` will be a minus sign if you set it in math, and you need a hyphen. In display math use `\textrm{$k$-distance}`

Comment: I think it depends on what `distance` denotes? Is it a function?  ... Or just go with David's recommendation. He know far more than I do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be using this as an operator, so let AMS take care of fonts and spacing:

[image]

Some possibilities:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator\kdista{\text{$k$-distance}}
\DeclareMathOperator\kdistb{\text{$k$-distance}}
\DeclareMathOperator\kdistc{\mathnormal{k}-distance}% I'd use this

\begin{document}


$\kdista(p)$ {\itshape $\kdista(p)$}


$\kdistb(p)$ {\itshape $\kdistb(p)$}


$\kdistc(p)$ {\itshape $\kdistc(p)$}

\end{document}
```

In general never use math italic for words, the font is designed to make adjacent letters *not* look like a word, also `-` will be a minus sign if you set it in math, and you need a hyphen.

For one-off use if you do not want to define an operator or use `amsmath`, or you need `k` to refer to a math italic k you could use `\textrm{$k$-distance}`

Comment: thanks an additional question. I have the equation in a `\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]` where every words is in italic. If I use `textrm` then distance is written in italic as well.  While if I use `DeclareMathOperator` k is not in math mode.

Comment: I believe `k` should be a mathnormal `k`...

Comment: ok best solution is probably `\DeclareMathOperator\kdist{\mathit{k}-distance}`

Comment: @Donbeo  no `\mathit` gives the text italic k not math italic, if you want an operator using math k I'll add to my question...

Comment: yes I would like `k` to be in math mode

Comment: @Donbeo with reference to your first comment. it is by design that math operators do not pick up the surrounding text font stye. It is quite common for fonts in math to have different meanings and a scalar should not turn into a vector for example just because  the surrounding text is bold.

Comment: @Donbeo updated answer

Comment: `\DeclareMathOperator{\kdistc}{\mathnormal{k}-distance}` should be sufficient.

Comment: @egreg yes I spotted that, feel free to edit:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- *please* explain the difference between `\mathit` and "math italic" in your answer.  the similarity of the names is most confusing to someone new!